# Udp image streaming, delphi indy10

Tags: delphi, tcp, udp, indy

i'm using delphi xe4 with indy10 component and i want to send an image from an Tidudpclient to Tidudpserver. I already done this operation with tcp component,but the same code didn't work with udp. how i can do this?
Thanks in advance!

> Timage(client)--->streamUDP-->Timage(server)

CLIENT SIDE----------------------------------------------- SEND IMAGE

```
var
    pic: tbitmap;
       Strm : TMemoryStream;
        img2:Timage;

    buffer:TIdBytes;
    begin

        try
          img2:=Timage.Create(nil);
          pic:=Tbitmap.Create;
          Takekpic(pic);     
          BMPtoJPG(pic,img2);
          Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
          img2.Picture.bitmap.SaveToStream(strm);
          Strm.Position:=0;
          ReadTIdBytesFromStream(Strm,buffer,SizeOf(Strm),0);
          IdTrivialFTPServer1.SendBuffer('192.168.17.128',1234,buffer);
        finally
             strm.Free;
          end; 
    end;
```

SERVER SIDE---------------------------------------------------- READ IMAGE

```
procedure TForm6.IdTrivialFTP1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
    var
Strm : TMemoryStream;
Jpg: TJpegImage;

begin
      Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try    

         WriteTIdBytesToStream(Strm,AData,SizeOf(AData),0);
         strm.Position:=0;
         Jpg := TJpegImage.Create;
         jpg.LoadFromStream(Strm);  <---- error while reading (JPEG Error #53)
         img1.Picture.assign(jpg);
      finally
         strm.Free;
         Jpg.Free;
      end;
end;
```

what can be wrong in this code?

Comment: http://www.codeforge.com/dlpre/139356 in this project You got everything You need.

Comment: How would you ensure that all the data u sent via UDP was received intact, in whole and in proper order ?

Comment: @FlashThunder i cannot download this project...

Comment: @Arioch'The see the answer to Remy Lebeau

Comment: "error while reading"  well... i know where to hire a spy to spy on you and tell me what the error was. Really, how do you execpt from anyone to understand your situation if you keep withholding factual information? http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: just `ShowNessage` how many is `SizeOf(AData)` and then open Delphi manual about what is `Dynamic array` and what are `reference types`. Saving single pointer to stream is not saving the data to stream! you should never pass the array but the element of array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdUDPClient` and `TIdUDPServer` do not support sending/receiving `TStream` data.  You can save your image data into a `TStream`, but you will have to send/receive it using `TIdBytes` chunks.

Alternatively, use `TIdTrivialFTP` and `TIdTrivialFTPServer` instead, which implement TFTP, a UDP-based file transfer protocol. They operate using `TStream` objects

**Update**: for example:

Client:

```
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
  Strm : TMemoryStream;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try 
        Takekpic(bmp);     
        jpg.Assign(bmp);
      finally
        bmp.Free;
      end;
      jpg.SaveToStream(Strm);
    finally
      jpg.Free;
    end;
    Strm.Position := 0;
    {
    These can be assigned ahead of time...
    IdTrivialFTP1.Host := '192.168.17.128';
    IdTrivialFTP1.Port := 1234;
    }
    IdTrivialFTP1.Put(Strm, 'image.jpg');
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

Server:

```
procedure TForm6.IdTrivialFTPServer1WriteFile(Sender: TObject; var FileName: String; const PeerInfo: TPeerInfo; var GrantAccess: Boolean; var AStream: TStream; var FreeStreamOnComplete: Boolean) of object;
begin
  if FileName = 'image.jpg' then
  begin
    GrantAccess := True;
    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    FreeStreamOnComplete := True;
  end else
    GrantAccess := False;
end;

{
If you set TIdTrivialFTPServer.ThreadedEvent to False, this event handler
runs in the context of the main thread, so the UI can be accessed safely.
If you set IdTrivialFTPServer.ThreadedEvent to True, this event handler
runs in the context of a worker thread, so you will have to manually
synchronize with the main thread when updating the UI...
}
procedure TForm6.IdTrivialFTPServer1TransferComplete(Sender: TObject; const Success: Boolean; const PeerInfo: TPeerInfo; var AStream: TStream; const WriteOperation: Boolean);
var
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  if WriteOperation and Success then
  begin
    jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      AStream.Position := 0;
      jpg.LoadFromStream(AStream);
      img1.Picture.Assign(jpg);
    finally
      jpg.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i want to create an image streaming, i think is not the best way to use ftp

Comment: @user1931849 TrivialFTP has nothing common with FTP - it is like JavaScript and Java having nothing in common

Comment: @user1931849: FTP and TFTP are not the same thing. FTP is TCP-based, and is a whole file management protocol, not just for transferring files. TFTP is UDP-based, and its sole purpose is transferring data and nothing else.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  how can i save my image data into a TStream and send/receive it using TIdBytes chunks? or how i can do this with trivial ftp?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i tried something with trivialftp and i saw that on the last version of indy10 it use also idbytes on the method Sendbuffer for example.

Comment: look the edits to my question, i found 2 methods like :WriteTIdBytesToStream and ReadTIdBytesFromStream, but i have an error at runtime. Can you take a look?

Comment: @RemyLebeau and indy's TFTP would ensure stream content integrity ? no missing frames, no bit flip-flops, no re-ordering of chunks ?

Comment: @Arioch'The he said that Tfpt use udp protocol = not ensure stream content integrity.

Comment: @user1931849 why ? TFTP may add this endurance just like TCP does. However if it does not - then you should, and i do not see you're doing it

Comment: TFTP ensures integrity, as it uses ACKs to ensure the receiver actually receives the data, and in the right order.

Comment: @user1931849: you are passing bad parameters to `ReadTIdBytesFromStream()` and `WriteTIdBytesToStream()` (use `Strm.Size` and `Length(AData)` instead of `SizeOf()`), you have way too many conversions on the sending side (bmp to jpg to bmp to stream to bytes), and you are misusing `TIdFTPTrivialServer` completely. Use the `TIdTrivialFTP.Put()` method on the sending side, and the `TIdTrivialFTPServer.OnWriteFile` event on the receiving side.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the support, but i have an error like this when i tried your code: "EidTFTPException with message 'Timeout'" on the client, istead on the server "EidTFTPillegalOperation with message 'Timeout'

Comment: @user1931849: TFTP is UDP-based, so packets can be lost. If `TIdTrivialFTP` does not receive a packet from the server within the `TIdTrivialFTP.ReceiveTimeout` interval (4 seconds by default), it will raise that exception. If `TIdTrivialFTPServer` does not receive a packet within 4.5 seconds (after retrying to send the previous packet several times if it has not been ACK'ed yet), it will raise that exception. So check your network connection, and use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to watch the TFTP packet traffic back and forth and make sure it is flowing correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: i know that but i tried in a local machine the server and the client and i have the same problem, think is near impossible that can't receive that stream in the same machine.