# Trouble sending JPG via Tidtrivialftp. File received is 0KB

Tags: file, delphi, udp, indy, transfer

I am setting up a software (SOFT1) that takes video frame grabs in JPG format and sent to another software (SOFT2) using Tidtrivialftp.

SOFT2 is to receive the Jpeg and display in a TImage for review.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The code is a cut and paste from another post on here. It seems to work but I get nothing in my TImage and if I try to save to disk I get a 0KB file.

I tried implementing the solution found on this link:

[Udp image streaming, delphi indy10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473596/udp-image-streaming-delphi-indy10/17473777#17473777)

Trying to send a small test.jpg which is only 2.48KB for testing purpose.

Client Side:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Myjpg: TJPEGImage;
  Strmkoko : TMemoryStream;
begin

try
    //Tried a lot of different ways to load the jpg into a stream. This is the latest one with same results.

    Strmkoko := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Myjpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    Myjpg.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Etienne\Desktop\MyVideo\a\test.jpg');
    Myjpg.SaveToStream(Strmkoko);
    Strmkoko.Position := 0;
    Image1.Picture.assign(Myjpg); //Confirming MyJpg is showing the picture by placing it in a TImage component before sending - All ok

    //Also tried to just put the filename instead of stream. - no difference
    IdtrivialFTPClientFrameGrab.Put(Strmkoko, 'test.jpg');

finally
    Strmkoko.Free;
    Myjpg.Free;
end;
end;
```

Server Side:

```
procedure TForm2.IdFTPServerFrameGrabTransferComplete(Sender: TObject;
  const Success: Boolean; const PeerInfo: TPeerInfo; var AStream: TStream;
  const WriteOperation: Boolean);
var
jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  if WriteOperation and Success then
  begin
    jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      jpg.LoadFromStream(AStream);
      jpg.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Etienne\Desktop\Pic\test.jpg'); //trying to save the jpg to check what I get and its 0KB
      img1.Picture.Assign(jpg); //This is the final place I want to send the stream
    finally
      jpg.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.IdFTPServerFrameGrabWriteFile(Sender: TObject;
  var FileName: string; const PeerInfo: TPeerInfo; var GrantAccess: Boolean;
  var AStream: TStream; var FreeStreamOnComplete: Boolean);
begin
  if Filename = 'test.jpg' then
  begin
    //Code does get in here when I debug
    GrantAccess := True;
    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    FreeStreamOnComplete := True;
  end else
    GrantAccess := False;
end;
```

I am expecting the file I am sending (test.jpg) to appear in img1 and also be saved in 'C:\Users\Etienne\Desktop\Pic\test.jpg'

The code does work in the way that it saved the file and assign it to img1 but its empty.

This is all done locally.

Its like "IdtrivialFTPClientFrameGrab.Put(Strmkoko, 'test.jpg');" is sending an empty file. But I have tried several ways to load the stream and always the same result.

I understand that TCP/IP would be better but I would like to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
E.

Comment: Host and port for IdtrivialFTPClientFrameGrab are previously assigned.

Comment: On a side note, you should avoid using `TJPEGImage.SaveToStream()` in this situation, as that will re-encode the image and lose image quality (JPG is a lossy format, quality is lost every time it is re-encoded). When sending a file, you should load it directly into your `TMemoryStream` first, and then load that stream into `TJPEGImage` if needed. When receiving a file, save the `TMemoryStream` directly to file, and load the stream into `TJPEGImage` if needed. This way, the receiver ends up with an *exact duplicate* of the original file, not a lossy version of it.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I posted here the last attempt but once I got it working I ended up just passing the file name to the put command as follow: "IdtrivialFTPClientFrameGrab.Put(Filename, 'test.jpg');"

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trials I figured out the problem. I do not know why it was omitted from the examples shown in the other posts but after you received the Stream you have to reset its position before you can load it...

AStream.Position := 0;

```
procedure TForm2.IdFTPServerFrameGrabTransferComplete(Sender: TObject;
  const Success: Boolean; const PeerInfo: TPeerInfo; var AStream: TStream;
  const WriteOperation: Boolean);
var
jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  if WriteOperation and Success then
  begin
    jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      AStream.Position := 0; // <----- insert here
      jpg.LoadFromStream(AStream);
      jpg.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Etienne\Desktop\Pic\test.jpg'); //trying to save the jpg to check what I get and its 0KB
      img1.Picture.Assign(jpg); //This is the final place I want to send the stream
    finally
      jpg.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I updated my earlier example to include the `Position` reset.  The reason `TIdTrivialFTPServer` does not reset the `Position` automatically is because the user of the component can provide custom streams and so the server does not make any assumptions about what the user intends to do with a stream after its transfer is complete. By default, an inbound transfer is merely saved to a disk file, and that does not require resetting the `Position`. But if the user wants to load the stream data into a UI, for instance, then the user needs to reset the `Position` as needed.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the input. The try loop prevented me from getting the "JPEG ERROR #42" which pointed me to the right solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387569/jpeg-error-42-on-assign